# How to structure my RSpec test folders, files and database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, functional-testing

I have been developing in RoR for more than a year now, but I'm just starting to use tests, using RSpec.

For standard model/controller tests, I usually don't have any problem, but the issue is that I want to test some complicated functional processes, and don’t really know how to structure my testing folders/files/database.

Here is a basic structure for my application:

```
class Customer
  has_one    :wallet
  has_many :orders    
  has_many :invoices, through: :orders
  has_many :invoice_summaries
end

class Wallet
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Order
  has_one    :invoice
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Invoice
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :invoice_summary
end

class InvoiceSummary
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many  :invoices
end
```

The main issue is that I want to simulate the lifecycle of my object, meaning:

- Instantiating customers and wallets which will be used for all the tests (without reinitializing)
- Simulating the time flow, creating and updating multiple orders/invoice objects and some invoice_summaries.

For the creation and update of the orders/invoices/invoice_summaries, I would like to have methods like

```
def create_order_1
  # code specific to create my first order, return the created order
end

def create_order_2
  # code specific to create my second order, return the created order
end
.
.
.
def create_order_n
  # code specific to create my n-th order, return the created order
end

def bill_order(order_to_bill)
  # generic code to do the billing of the order passed as parameter
end

def cancel_order(order_to_cancel)
  # generic code to cancel the order passed as parameter
end
```

I’ve already found the gem [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) for simulating the time flow. Hence, I would like to have an easy to understand final test that looks like

```
# Code for the initialization of customers and wallets object

describe "Wallet should be equal to 0 after first day" do
  Timecop.freeze(Time.new(2015,7,1))
  first_request = create_request_1
  first_request.customer.wallet.value.should? == 0
end

describe "Wallet should be equal to -30 after second day" do
  Timecop.freeze(Time.new(2015,7,2))
  bill_order(first_request)
  second_order = create_order_2
  first_request.customer.wallet.value.should? == -30
end

describe "Wallet should be equal to -20 after third day" do 
  Timecop.freeze(Time.new(2015,7,3))
  bill_order(second_request)
  cancel_order(first_request)
  first_request.customer.wallet.value.should? == -20
end

describe "Three first day invoice_summary should have 3 invoices" do
  Timecop.freeze(Time.new(2015,7,4))
  invoice_summary = InvoiceSummary.create(
      begin_date: Date.new(2015,7,1),
      end_date: Date.new(2015, 7,3)
  ) # real InvoiceSummary method
  invoice_summary.invoices.count.should? == 3
end
```

Does anyone already have such tests? Are there good practices for the structuring of object factories, writing tests and so on?

For example, I've been told that a good idea would be to put the Customer/Wallet creation in a db/seed.rb file, but I don't really know what to do with it afterwards.

Comment: @HunterStevens I believe your edit is wrong, because you removed some logic about the orders. 
`def create_order_n; end` IS different from `def create_order_1; end` `def create_order_2;end` since @vincent wanted to express the need to do 2 completly differents things. You should be carefull before editing like this...

Comment: @Erowlin please roll back my edit then. I was trying to clean up a very long post. Sorry.

Comment: NP, just be careful next time ;). BTW, thank you for your edit, it started from a good intention !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fully answering your question could fill and has filled books, so I can only outline an answer here.

Regarding creating objects to test,

- db/seeds.rb isn't for test data, but for static data, not changed by users, that's required for the application to run, whether in development or testing or production. Common examples of this kind of data include country codes and user roles.
- There are two general approaches to creating test data, fixtures and factories.

  - Fixtures are the out-of-the-box Rails method. They are created once when the test database is created. They're fast when you have many tests, because they're only created once at the beginning of the test suite. However, they warp tests because they encourage writing tests around existing fixtures, so I strongly recommend against them.
  - Factories are object creation utilities. You create the objects you need in each test and delete or roll them back at the end. Most Rails projects that use factories use FactoryGirl. That's what I recommend.

  Both approaches put object creation code in its own files in a different directory than your specs, which keeps it from junking up your spec files. If you search SO for "fixtures or factories" you'll find lots more discussion of both.

Your specs will be easier to understand if you put all of the important values, which in this case include dates and amounts, in the specs where they can be seen and compared to the results that you're asserting. (Otherwise you need to memorize the dates and the amounts in your test objects to understand the specs.) You could give the object creation methods in your test `date` and `amount` parameters. You might need less methods then. If you used FactoryGirl it might just be a question of specifying each object's `created_at` and `amount` attributes. Note also that Rails has methods like `1.day.from_now`; if you create objects with dates specified that way you might not need timecop.

Regarding how to lay out RSpec specs in the filesystem, at the top level, just make the layout identical to that of your Rails app:

```
app/
  controllers/
    bars_controller.rb
    foos_controller.rb
  models/
    bar.rb
    foo.rb
    ...
  ...

spec/
  controllers/
    bars_controller_spec.rb
    foos_controller_spec.rb
    ...
  models/
    bar_spec.rb
    foo_spec.rb
    ...
  ...
```

If your specs for a single class get too big, it's a sign that the class is too big. Find some pattern to break it up and test the pieces individually. If you really can't break up the class (a rare situation), turn the class's spec file into a directory of spec files, as I described in [How to break down super long specs in RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380014/how-to-break-down-super-long-specs-in-rspec/31892456).

Comment: More details on [RSpec suggested directory structure here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/directory-structure).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`FactoryGirl`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) for your task. Configure it as described in the documentation, and then just use it like this:

```
# factories.rb
factory :order do
end

# your spec
first_order = create(:order, ...) # configure parameters of order in-place
```

Or have specific Factories handle different types of requests:

```
# factories.rb
factory :expensive_order, class: Order do
  amount 999 # have 'amount' field of Order be equal to 999
end

# your spec
first_order = create(:expensive_order)
```

You can have FactoryGirl handle your associations automatically:

```
factory :order do
  association :user # automatically create User association
end
```

You are describing the exact problem which FactoryGirl's developers are aiming to solve.